# Is there any example source code for java and spring boot integration available for docusign?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate my spring boot application with docusign for sending the documents and getting it signed from the users. I am not able to do it because I am not getting as how to get the JWT token to call the API's. I have downloaded the java code example from the docusign and configured accordingly. I am able to call the API's from the postman properly, But when I call any API from my application by rest template it gives me 302 redirect found. Is there any example project with java available for this ? Am I missing something.

Comment: If it's working with the postman then you should first check whether you'r requesting the docu sign service with proper grant type and request method using rest template.

Comment: Hi @nani. Are you using spring security with spring boot? Which java code example did you download? Thanks!

Comment: I have built my own application using those two. @fongfong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the solution myself. It's the issue with the session management and security in the example code. If I call any API from rest template there is no session at the beginning and it requires a JWT. So I need to pass a session Id in the header which is active and holds the value of the current user.

Comment: Hi Nani, can you please help with code, I am badly struggling. any github repo or any reference will be helpful

Comment: theshrutikasharma@gmail.com if you can send over mail, that will also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The Code Example Launchers that we have for Java do operate on SpringBoot and has an example framework for creating JWT tokens, they should work for you out of the box.

Usually when we see someone getting stuck at a 302 it's because the application isn't following provided redirects -- most commonly when the baseUrl being targeted is using http over https.

Can you doublecheck your baseUrl and make sure that's the case? It's common to see 302s like this but not so much for them to be a roadblock.

Comment: I have figured out the solution myself. It's the issue with the session management and security in the example code. If I call any API from rest template there is no session at the beginning and it requires a JWT. So I need to pass a session Id in the header which is active and holds the value of the current user. Any way Thanks for your help. And it would be much better if some demo application like MyHR or MyUni can be given in Java spring boot. @Matt King DS